# tile edit view wrong context for vocabularies

Tags: plone

I have a persistent tile that has a choice field:

```
subjects = schema.List(
    title=_(u"Subjects"),
    value_type=schema.Choice(
        vocabulary='my.subjects'
    ),
)
```

but this is failing on edit view rendering like this:

```
2013-05-22 18:37:56 ERROR Zope.SiteErrorLog 1369240676.330.546121806344 http://localhost:8082/plumi/@@edit-tile/tagcloud.tile/home-cloud
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
  Module plone.z3cform.layout, line 70, in __call__
  Module plone.z3cform.layout, line 54, in update
  Module plone.app.tiles.browser.edit, line 48, in update
  Module plone.app.tiles.browser.base, line 55, in update
  Module plone.z3cform.fieldsets.extensible, line 59, in update
  Module plone.z3cform.patch, line 30, in GroupForm_update
  Module z3c.form.group, line 125, in update
  Module plone.app.tiles.browser.base, line 71, in updateWidgets
  Module z3c.form.field, line 275, in update
  Module z3c.form.browser.orderedselect, line 50, in update
  Module z3c.form.browser.widget, line 70, in update
  Module z3c.form.widget, line 199, in update
  Module z3c.form.widget, line 193, in updateTerms
  Module zope.component._api, line 107, in getMultiAdapter
  Module zope.component._api, line 120, in queryMultiAdapter
  Module zope.component.registry, line 238, in queryMultiAdapter
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 532, in queryMultiAdapter
  Module z3c.form.term, line 174, in CollectionTerms
  Module zope.schema._field, line 352, in bind
  Module Zope2.App.schema, line 33, in get
  Module my.vocabularies, line 22, in __call__
  Module Products.CMFCore.utils, line 10, in check_getToolByName
  Module Products.CMFCore.utils, line 120, in getToolByName
  AttributeError: portal_catalog
```

This happen because the `context` passed to the vocabulary call is the data dictionary of the tile. It happens also when using `SearchableTextSourceBinder` in another field:

`source=SearchableTextSourceBinder(
            {'is_folderish': True},
            default_query='path:'
        )`

that makes plone.app.vocabularies.catalog fail:

```
Module plone.app.vocabularies.catalog, line 237, in __call__
  Module plone.app.vocabularies.catalog, line 144, in __init__
  Module Products.CMFCore.utils, line 10, in check_getToolByName
  Module Products.CMFCore.utils, line 120, in getToolByName
AttributeError: portal_catalog
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, if it's by design, but when a persistent tile is edited, context sensitive vocabulary will get its context (persistent tile data dictionary) without any acquisition wrapping. Therefore all lookups which rely on acquisition will fail.

You could try fixing your vocabulary to use portal root as its context for `getToolByName`-looksup using either `plone.api.portal.get()` or `zope.component.hooks.getSite()`.

If you really need the current context, an ugly way would be to get `zope.globalrequest.getRequest().get("PUBLISHED")` which should be the current publishable context found by ZPublisher. It's usually a view, but you can get your context object from its acquisition chain. Of course, you should be very defensive with that approach.

Comment: well, actually the problem is not that I miss the context for getting tools :) I can fix that in my vocab and we can fix p.a.vocabularies. The problem is - like you said - having "context sensitive vocabulary". Now the question is: shouldn't we fix this in p.a.tiles (or wherever)?

Comment: If you have time, you could experiment with implementing a custom TileDataManager (adapter), which would 1) return acquisition wrapped dict-like object when getting the data, 2) strip acquisition wrapping when saving the data. Since it's adapter you could register it against your custom browser layer and no overrides is needed. For TileDataManager, see: https://github.com/plone/plone.tiles/blob/master/plone/tiles/data.py

A change is that DataManager-lookups in z3c.from will fail if the wrapper does not adapt to dm-adapters registered for dict.